# Expect element contains class name puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, classname

so I have an element with a certain id, let's say: #id = test. This element has a class like .form-thumbs-up and I want to obtain an assertion that this element contains 'thumbs-up' in its class but I have no idea how to do it.
I tried

```
  const thumbsUp = await this.page.$('[id="test"]');
  const className = await thumbsUp.getProperty('className');
  expect(className).toContain('thumbs-up');
```

but I receive an error like:   Expected object: .... to contain value thumbs-up failed.
Do you have any idea how to solve it? Maybe I need to try another approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getProperty`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#jshandlegetpropertypropertyname) returns [JS handle](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-jshandle). You need [one more step](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue) to get a string:

```js
const className = await (await thumbsUp.getProperty('className')).jsonValue();
```